# Why is this query slow, where id in (sub select that returns null)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a hard time understanding why this query is taking more than 1ms.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT AVG("adverts"."price") 
FROM "adverts" WHERE "adverts"."type" IN ('Businesses::Restaurant') 
AND "adverts"."discarded_at" IS NULL AND "adverts"."visible" = true 
AND ("adverts"."city_location_id" = 56 
     OR "adverts"."city_location_id" IN (SELECT "city_locations"."id" 
                                         FROM "city_locations" 
                                         WHERE "city_locations"."type" IN ('Arrondissement') 
                                        AND "city_locations"."arrondissement_city_id" = 56));

QUERY PLAN

 Aggregate  (cost=6583.49..6583.50 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=21.702..21.702 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on adverts  (cost=6.31..6533.88 rows=19842 width=4) (actual time=0.462..21.684 rows=44 loops=1)
         Filter: ((discarded_at IS NULL) AND visible AND ((type)::text = 'Businesses::Restaurant'::text) AND ((city_location_id = 56) OR (hashed SubPlan 1)))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 46217
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Index Scan using index_city_locations_on_arrondissement_city_id on city_locations  (cost=0.29..6.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: (arrondissement_city_id = 56)
                 Filter: ((type)::text = 'Arrondissement'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.173 ms
 Execution Time: 21.739 ms
```

The execution time is **21ms**

If I execute the sub request I get:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "city_locations"."id" FROM "city_locations" WHERE "city_locations"."type" IN ('Arrondissement') AND "city_locations"."arrondissement_city_id" = 56;
 id 
----
(0 rows)

QUERY PLAN

 Index Scan using index_city_locations_on_arrondissement_city_id on city_locations  (cost=0.29..6.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (arrondissement_city_id = 56)
   Filter: ((type)::text = 'Arrondissement'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.233 ms
 Execution Time: 0.075 ms
```

execution time is: **0.075ms**, super fast and the result is **NULL**.

When I replace the sub request by its result **NULL** it is super fast.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT AVG("adverts"."price") 
FROM "adverts" WHERE "adverts"."type" IN ('Businesses::Restaurant') 
AND "adverts"."discarded_at" IS NULL AND "adverts"."visible" = true 
AND ("adverts"."city_location_id" = 56 
     OR "adverts"."city_location_id" IN (NULL));

QUERY PLAN

 Aggregate  (cost=162.66..162.67 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.309..0.310 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on adverts  (cost=4.72..162.55 rows=42 width=4) (actual time=0.082..0.278 rows=44 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (city_location_id = 56)
         Filter: ((discarded_at IS NULL) AND visible AND ((type)::text = 'Businesses::Restaurant'::text))
         Heap Blocks: exact=42
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_adverts_on_city_location_id_and_visible  (cost=0.00..4.71 rows=42 width=0) (actual time=0.043..0.044 rows=44 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((city_location_id = 56) AND (visible = true))
 Planning Time: 0.395 ms
 Execution Time: 0.412 ms
```

The execution time is **0.412 ms**

My question is why is the first request slow when its separate requests are fast?

Do I miss some optimization due to the **WHERE IN** clause?

Comment: `OR "adverts"."city_location_id" IN (NULL)` looks suspect...

Comment: Yeah that's my suspect way to test if I can make the query faster

Answer (score 1):

First:simplify

---

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT AVG(ad.price) 
FROM adverts a
WHERE a.type IN ('Businesses::Restaurant') 
AND a.discarded_at IS NULL
AND a.visible = true 
AND (a.city_location_id = 56 
     OR a.city_location_id IN (
        SELECT c.id
        FROM city_locations c
        WHERE c.type IN ('Arrondissement')                                  
        AND c.arrondissement_city_id = 56))
        ;
```

---

Next:rewrite the`IN(...)` into `EXISTS(...)`

---

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT AVG(a.price)
FROM adverts a
WHERE a.type IN ('Businesses::Restaurant') 
AND a.discarded_at IS NULL
AND a.visible = true 
AND (a.city_location_id = 56 
     OR EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM city_locations c
        WHERE a.city_location_id = c.id 
        AND c.type IN ('Arrondissement')
        AND c.arrondissement_city_id = 56))
        ;
```

---

Now,you can push the ugly `OR` into the subquery:
(assuming the subquery has lower cardinality)

-> The optimizer will probably *not* be smart enough to push this `OR` term down

---

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT AVG(a.price)  
FROM adverts a
WHERE a.type IN ('Businesses::Restaurant') 
AND a.discarded_at IS NULL
AND a.visible = true 
AND EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM city_locations c
        WHERE a.city_location_id = c.id
        AND (c.type IN ('Arrondissement') AND c.arrondissement_city_id = 56
            OR c.city_location_id = 56
                )
        ;
```

---

If the subquery has a small enough result set, you *could* try to move it to a CTE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the last suggestion runs in 1ms which is great. Now the query is generated by an ORM, either I can make it generate this query or I have to run raw SQL. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you cannot conrtol your ORM, it will controll you.#xyz-alert

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening in your scenario, is that the sub-query is being executed once for each row in your parent result set. So multiply the run-time of the sub-query by the number of records in your parent result set.

A way to re-write this query to speed it up would be to use a `WITH` clause at the start of your query:

```
WITH cities AS (
    SELECT "city_locations"."id" AS id
    FROM "city_locations" 
    WHERE "city_locations"."type" IN ('Arrondissement') 
        AND "city_locations"."arrondissement_city_id" = 56
)
SELECT AVG("adverts"."price") 
FROM "adverts" 
WHERE "adverts"."type" IN ('Businesses::Restaurant') 
    AND "adverts"."discarded_at" IS NULL AND "adverts"."visible" = true 
    AND ("adverts"."city_location_id" = 56 
    OR "adverts"."city_location_id" IN (SELECT id FROM cities));
```

This may speed it up some in the case of no records or very few, but it is still executing a `SELECT` for each record. This just cuts down on accessing and filtering the `city_locations` table directly.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it takes the same amount of time

Answer (score 0):

Think you might be assuming that the query inside the IN is definitely executed first, as though it were standalone, and then the result fed into the outer, at which point "it should realize that it's null and wont produce any result, so quit early" - so you're expecting the big query to take the same time as it takes the DB to decide the small query produces NULL. In practice the big query will be rewritten by the db optimizer in some way so that the way it's executed is different to the conceptual model of execution you've formed in your mind. This time round the DB's picked a sub-optimal optimization for it and is taking longer to connect the data up, then realize the result is null.

This is a very different scenario to hard coding your NULL like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE x IN (null)` - there'll be a specific optimization that that decides this is a no-op and you may even find parts of a complex query that includes an operation that is always false, such as this, are not executed at all. Th MySQL manual goes into some fantastic detail about query optimization, if your curiosity is intense enough :)

Comment: Ok, I thought it was an easy way form me to see if I could optimize the query, as each of its components are fast. I may need to read about query optimization :)